# Linux Substitution: Add spaces between brackets in a file using sed

Tags: linux, vim, sed

I would like to add spaces between my braces when there is content in the brackets. For example, I would like to substitute the following line

```
sorted ([] if interfaces is None else list(interfaces[temp])))
```

to

```
sorted ( [] if interfaces is None else list( interfaces[ temp ] ) ) )
```

I am trying to use sed inside vim but I am unable to get the regex correctly. Anyone have any idea of the pattern required to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried, lookaheads etc? https://www.inputoutput.io/lookbehind-lookahead-regex-in-vim/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In vim it would be the following two commands:

```
:%s/(\([ )]\)\@!/( /g
:%s/\([ (]\)\@<!)/ )/g
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$ a="sorted ([] if interfaces is None else list(interfaces[temp])))"; echo $a | sed -r 's/\(/\( /g;s/\)/ \)/g'
sorted ( [] if interfaces is None else list( interfaces[temp] ) ) )
```

`sed` replace each '(' adding space after: '( ' and each ')' adding space before: ' )'